# I have an IndexOutOfBoundsException and can't figure out why

Tags: java, swing, exception, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, and I don't know why.

I have several text fields (Integer, Double, and others) and I need to use them according the information on the `ArrayList<String> tagContentAL`

Here's my code:

```
jLabelAL = new ArrayList<>();
jTextFieldAL = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    jLabelAL.add(new JLabel("" + tagNamesAL.get(i)));
    switch (tagContentAL.get(i).toString()) {
        case "int":
                jTextFieldAL.add((JTextField) new tools.IntegerTextField(simulation));
                break;
        case "double":
        case "float":
                jTextFieldAL.add((JTextField) new tools.DoubleTextField(simulation));
                break;
        case "*":
                jTextFieldAL.add((JTextField) new JTextField());
                break;
    }

    jTextFieldAL.get(i).addKeyListener(keyEvent); //IndexOutOfBoundsException in this line
    p1.add(jLabelAL.get(i));
    p1.add(jTextFieldAL.get(i));
}
```

What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Where is `size` defined?

Comment: tagNamesAL.size() = size ?

Comment: are you sure that the cases block is complete? If there's on option not covered, there wont be a JTextField added .. try to insert a default case to check.

Comment: size is defined above `int size = tagNamesAL.size()` (something like this)

Comment: @EduardoRocha What do you mean by `(something like this)`?. YOu are no sure about this?

Comment: yes I'm sure, I didn't mentioned it's private but the declaration is there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not necessarily the case that you're adding an element to `jTextFieldAL` on each iteration, since the switch has no default case. If you haven't added an element to `jTextFieldAL` on every iteration up to and including the current one, then you'll read out of bounds when you do `jTextFieldAL.get(i)`, since the last element you added (if any) will have an index strictly less than `i`. In practical terms, this means you'll get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` on the first iteration in which you fail to add an element to `jTextFieldAL`.

Comment: @nachokk: He doesn't pass `size` to it though - he creates an empty list. Am I missing something?

Comment: @nachokk: There's a difference between size and capacity - it might create it with a default *capacity* of 10, but I doubt that it creates it with a default *size* of 10. The index check is done on the size, not the capacity.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `jTextFieldAL.get(i)` may not exist cause `i >= jTextFieldAl.size()` . Cause in your switch statement may don't enter in any case.

> Throws: IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the index is out of range
>   (index < 0 || index >= size())

As @camickr says you shouldn't use `KeyListener` (you need to have focus and may not always work) you can use `DocumentListener` or `KeyBindings` for your purposes.

Comment: +1, also, don't use a KeyListener on the text field. Instead you should probably be using a `DocumentListener`.

Comment: Yes, anything but a KeyListener should generally be used.

Answer (score 3):

After the for cycle i is greater than size, and you try to read something from jLabelAL.get(i), that is out of boundary -> that cause your exception

Comment: The code ends at the end of the for loop. You can't see what happens after i is added up to the value of size.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have 'default' in your switch block.
jTextFieldAL length may not increase in loop iteration. 
So you will hit IndexOutOfBoundException

Comment: -1, already mentioned twice. No need to clutter the forum with duplicate answers.